EC2 GUI in ubuntu 24.04 LTS
How come I got no answer yet for this simple question, why can't I get a GUI working in an ubuntu 24.04 LTS instance ?
Why is this not working in ubuntu 24.04 LTS
EC2 GUI
    • Installation
        ○ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
        ○ sudo apt install tigervnc-standalone-server tigervnc-viewer
        ○ sudo apt install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
        ○ vncserver :1
            § To kill: vncserver -kill :1
        ○ Configured a .vnc/xstartup for tightvnc but later installed tigervnc and removed it and none exist now
        ○ Added tunnel to Putty 
            § L5901 -> localhost:5901
        ○ Configured SSH to TBG (see info under Jenkins and TBG for details) to work with git
        ○ Disabled screen lock for gnome since can't unlock
            § See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224957/i-cannot-log-in-a-vnc-session-after-the-screen-locks-authentification-error
            § And solution: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/gnome-disable-screen-lock
                □  GUI provided a 2nd lock option that I also disabled
    • Running
        ○ Start with: vncserver from /home/ubuntu
            § My issue was a zero byte xstartup file under .vnc that I deleted and all is well
            § Also don't run with sudo as it starts for the root user and then Eclipse messes up a bunch of file permissions.
        ○ Stuck with lock
            § Finally ran: sudo loginctl unlock-sessions
            § And then started my vnc viewer session and it was unlocked 
    • Get Firefox to work (fine with TigerVNC)
        ○ Only from terminal for now
        ○ See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1462654

